# Set Theory Proof Help needed.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have a question in my exercises that I am lost on. It is a set theory question, simple enough. However, it has a constraint on it that has made it dubiously more difficult for me. I will write it out in its entirety below.

Let $R,S,T$ be sets. Without using Theorem $6.24$, prove that
$(R \cap S)∪(R \cap T) \subseteq R \cap (S \cup T)$.

Theorem $6.24$ (as per my textbook) is Distributivity for Sets, the property that allows me to simplify and prove this quickly. Without this tool, I'm helpless with this proof. Any and all help is appreciated! Stay safe guys.

Comment: You can just show directly that any element in $(R \cap S) \cup (R \cap T)$ is also in $R \cap (S \cup T)$. That's the way you usually show a set is contained in another.

Comment: Do it by what I call element-chasing. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of the lefthand side and show that it must be an element of the righthand side; then let $x$ be an arbitrary element of the righthand side and show that it must be an element of the lefthand side.

Comment: @Sverre Thats precisely the property I am restricted from using, which is why this question is difficult.

Comment: I know this may be asking a bit much, but I am unfamiliar with that methodology, how would I begin to show that? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: You could try proving by contradiction as well. Suppose $x \notin R \cap (S \cup T)$. Then, try showing that $x \notin (R \cap S) \cup (R \cap T)$.

Comment: @AurumAmishana hmm okay I figured distributivity states that $(R \cap S) \cup (R \cap T) = R \cap (S \cup T)$. But then how do you define $\subseteq$?

Comment: That is what I was grappling with, but as per the answers below, it appears that it is not needed to literally 'define' ⊆. I believe the answers to be correct.

Comment: The answers below prove any element in $(R \cap S)∪(R \cap T)$ is also in $R \cap (S \cup T)$, which is how $\subseteq$ is usually defined, and which is what you said you weren't allowed to use...

Comment: @Sverre You are correct, I misread the theorem provided, and it does indeed utilize that definition. So, by way of this arbitrary condition, those answers are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below a proof , with an emphasise on logical structure

Dsjunctive syllogism is the following inference rule :

from (X OR Y) and ( not-X) , infer : Y

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in(R∩S)∪(R∩T)$.

Thus, $x\in R$.

Also, $x\in S$ or $x\in T$.

Thus, $x\in S∪T$ and from here $x\in  R∩(S∪T).$

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that if $x\in (R \cap S)\cup (R \cap T)$ then $x\in R\cap (S\cup T)$. Try doing this using the definition of $\cap$ and $\cup$.

I'll help you get started - if $x$ belongs to the LHS, then $x$ either $x$ is in both $R$ and $S$, or $x$ is in both $R$ and $T$. What does this tell you about $x$? How can you show it belongs to the set on the RHS using this information?

If you need more help let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Element-chasing:

Let $x \in (R\cap S)\cup (R \cap T)$;

Then $x \in (R \cap S)$ or  $\in (R \cap T)$.

1) $x \in (R \cap S):$

Then $x \in R$ and  $x \in S$, and

since $S\subset S \cup T,$  we have $x \in S\cup T$;

Summing up:  $x \in (R \cap S)$ then

$x \in R$ and $x \in S \cup T,$ i.e

$x \in R \cap (S \cup T)$

2) $x \in (R \cap T).$ Can you finish?